# Variable names missing in Visual Studio 2015 Locals Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When a breakpoint is hit, Visual Studio's Locals window no longer shows the variable names for items (excluding "this" and passed parameters). This seemingly happened out of nowhere, as I made no recent changes that should have affected this.

[image: Locals Window]

Is there any way to get variable names showing again?

Comment: Well, hopefully this bug will be fixed when it ships.  Just one more week.

Comment: @HansPassant It is quite annoying. Hovering over variables doesn't even show their value.

Comment: I still have this problem is VS2015 update 2